# Automatically switch to wifi connection when wired is not working?

Tags: wireless, wired, automatic

I have a server which needs to be online as much as possible. This is why I have a backup wifi connection for my main wired one. But I have to manually switch to it when the wired one dies. Could I use some script to do this automatically? I can manage to write one to detect whether wired connection is working but which commands I can use to switch between wired to wifi?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this: https://smallhacks.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/monitoring-wan-status-on-openwrt-using-alarm-pinger/

The script could trigger the wireless connection and vice versa.